# How to include a sort criteria into a pivot_table function?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Below is my code where I used pivot_table function on df dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State' : ['B','B','A','A','C', 'C'],
           'Age' : ['1 to 5', '6 to 10', '1 to 5', '6 to 10', '1 to 5', '6 to 10'],
           'Vaccinated' : [80, 20, 30, 60, 10, 15],
           'Population': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
           'Percentage' : [0.80, 0.20, 0.30, 0.60, 0.10,0.15]})

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=["Vaccinated", "Population","Percentage"],index=["State", "Age"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

The results from the earlier code:

```
                   Percentage  Population  Vaccinated
State Age                                        
A     1 to 5         0.30         100          30
      6 to 10        0.60         100          60
B     1 to 5         0.80         100          80
      6 to 10        0.20         100          20
C     1 to 5         0.10         100          10
      6 to 10        0.15         100          15
```

However, I want to sort my records so that State B is at the top followed by A then C.
Rational is because State B has 100% vaccinated (60%+40%), State A has 90% (60%+30%) & State C has 25%. Try to add in sort a few times and i encountered errors.

May I seek advice how to add in a sort criteria during or after pivot_table so that i can achieve the results below?

```
               Percentage  Population  Vaccinated
State Age                                        
B     1 to 5         0.80         100          80
      6 to 10        0.20         100          20
A     1 to 5         0.30         100          30
      6 to 10        0.60         100          60
C     1 to 5         0.10         100          10
      6 to 10        0.15         100          15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to get the total `Vaccinated` per `State`, then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) to determine the order that the states should be in, then we can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the `State` level to reorder based on the group total:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(
    index=df1.groupby(level='State')['Vaccinated'].sum()
        .sort_values(ascending=False).index,
    level='State'
)
```

`df`:

```
               Percentage  Population  Vaccinated
State Age                                        
B     1 to 5         0.80         100          80
      6 to 10        0.20         100          20
A     1 to 5         0.30         100          30
      6 to 10        0.60         100          60
C     1 to 5         0.10         100          10
      6 to 10        0.15         100          15
```

Comment: Thanks Henry for the explanation. The detailed explanation allows me to understand & follow the code in small steps. I noticed the 1st and your sharing does not use pivot_table to do the sorting. I assumed that is the limitation of pivot_table function?

Comment: Sorting within a pivot table is limited to a single column. The pivot table does not know the State level totals until after the table is already pivoted which is why we need to reindex the pivot table afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make helper column with group sum, sort the df by it and then delete it:

```
df1 = df1.assign(Sum=df1.groupby(level=0).Vaccinated.transform('sum')).\
    sort_values(by='Sum', ascending=False).drop(columns=['Sum'])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
               Percentage  Population  Vaccinated
State Age                                        
B     1 to 5         0.80         100          80
      6 to 10        0.20         100          20
A     1 to 5         0.30         100          30
      6 to 10        0.60         100          60
C     1 to 5         0.10         100          10
      6 to 10        0.15         100          15
```